# receive SMPP messages using EasySMPP

Tags: c#, smpp

I'm developing a SMS sending and receiving application using EasySMPP library. So,I was able to send sms using this library but I can't receive messages using EasySMPP library. Because I can't find a methods for SMPP message receiving in EasySMPP, I'm trying more than 1 week to do it. But,I couldn't succeed yet. Please anyone know how to overcome this problem, let me know.

Comment: any idea for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, doing months of research I found a .net SMPP library for which can be used to send and received messages via SMPP protocol. The library link is https://www.tops.com.pl/en/smscc/

That is very easy to use library and sending messages at high speeds.

Answer (score 0):

[InetLab](http://inetlab.com/Products/Inetlab.SMPP.aspx) provides a high level library for receive/send `SMPP` messages. There are useful examples also illustrating how it works. Whole library needed to buy if you want to edit SDK code.